Does the Colorado 10 minute break law apply to salaried workers?
My understanding is that in Colorado, all workers (whether hourly or salaried), are allowed to take a 10 minute break, on the clock, for each 4 hours they work in a shift. Is this correct?
Here is the official document, where the relevant portion is at the top of page 2. I see nothing in that document that restricts this regulation to only be for hourly employees.
Some might think that this is irrelevant for those who have a salary, but some employers require their full-time salaried employees to clock in at least 40 hours a week.

VTC - The people who can answer this would be the Colorado department of Labor and Employment - not us.

How would you meaningfully define "salaried" here, given that you're asking this based on your time being tracked (i.e. whether the 10 minutes counts as part of "your work time" or not). This seems like a semantical question based on what you define as being salaried and how this related to hours worked.

@TheDemonLord: Disagree - the consensus for legal questions is that they are on-topic if our target audience should be expected to know the answer (What is asking for legal advice?). So this Q seems OK to me.

The official document you've linked is NOT a regulation, it is an information notice on how the regulations may be interpreted by the Colorado Department of Labor and Employment.

For shifts of over 5 consecutive hours, all employees are entitled to
uninterrupted, duty-free meal periods of at least 30 minutes (unless
the COMPS Order makes them exempt)

Emphasis added.
You should read the appropriate regulations mentioned in this document, or seek advice from the Colorado Department of Labor and Employment.
